# Table UI C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I need some GUI that can hold 3 columns of of text (that i would like to be aligned). I'll add and delete rows. What control can i use and how do i add in the 3 items?

Comment: Platform, please. Web Forms, Winforms, WPF, SilverLight?

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataGrid control if you are using WindowsForms. It allows for complete control over the display of headers and you can manually add/remove rows at will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WinForms, you could use the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) to provide this functionality. The cell contents could be a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) or a read-only [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx). You could also use a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(VS.71).aspx). Of course, there is always the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) as well.

In WPF, you have many more options on how to achieve this, but you could use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) (similar to [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) in concept) or a [DataGrid](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047).

Answer (score 0):

A ListView control always works if you're looking for something simple and effective.